# Ошибка BASEDIR на php7.3 - Как исправить?

Tags: php, warning, php7.3

Старый код не работает на php7.3 получаю предупреждение:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant BASEDIR - assumed 'BASEDIR' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sitecopy\includes\bbcodes\url_bbcode_include.php on
>   line 27
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant BASEDIR - assumed 'BASEDIR' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sitecopy\includes\bbcodes\url_bbcode_include.php on
>   line 27
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant INCLUDES - assumed 'INCLUDES' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sitecopy\includes\bbcodes\url_bbcode_include.php on
>   line 29

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить? Не силён я в кодировании. Вот две строчки старого кода:

```
$guest_msg = '[ ссылка скрыта ] ( <a href="'.BASEDIR.'register.php"><u>регистрация</u></a> | <a href="'.BASEDIR.'login.php"><u>вход</u></a> )';

$pathto = ($friendlyurl?BASEDIR.$friendlypath.'?':INCLUDES.'bbcodes/url_bbcode_include.php?');
```

Comment: Думаю, что старого кода маловато показано. Ошибка может находиться в соседних строках.

Comment: ошибка означает что не опередела константа BASEDIR. И INCLUDES тоже не определена. Почему они не определены - мы не знаем. Это твой код, а не наш. попробуй проверить во всех ли файлах используется полный РНР тег, <?php, а не короткий.